# Cannot pass parameter in xmldp query

Tags: xml, web-services, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I have a webservice that I am calling a method from using xmldp query. It looks like this:

```
<Query>
<Method Name="MyRequest" Namespace="MySchema">
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="db">
           <DefaultValue>DefaultDB</DefaultValue>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter Name="Param1">
           <DefaultValue>DefaultParam1</DefaultValue>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter Name="Param2">
           <DefaultValue>DefaultParam2</DefaultValue>
        </Parameter>
    </Parameters>
</Method>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">
            MyPath/path....
</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

The problem I am seeing is that when I execute the query, the db and Param1 parameters pass fine, but the Param2 parameter ALWAYS passes as a null! Any ideas on why it is always a null instead of my default value? I've confirmed that the parameter is already coming in as null before it reaches the webservice, so it is not a problem with my method in the webservice. I've also checked the report parameters, everything is the same between all three. Sorry if I'm being too vague, I'm new to SSRS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer for anybody with this problem in the future...

There was nothing wrong with my query itself, but it turns out you need to set the query parameters in alphabetical order in the Dataset Properties. Not sure why this is, but that's what got my Dataset to work.

```
Right Click the Dataset > Dataset Properties > Parameters
```

Comment: Kbye, thanks alot for posting your answer. I had a similiar issue and had tried everything to resolve it and your post came to the rescue.